# using realloc() leads to segmentation fault after passing specific memory value

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, segmentation-fault, realloc

I encountered a problem which after expanding memory with `realloc()`, Segmentation fault reached when it try to reach specific memory number. 135,126th char address to be exact.

But, that mark never a problem if I allocate memory with `malloc()` bigger in the first place.

Here is my experiment with C that run on linux AMD64 compiled with gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SECT_SIZE 25
#define SECT_EXTEND_SIZE 100
#define MAX_SECT_TEST 18000

void extend_memory(char *c_memory, int *i_current_sect_size){

    char *c_temp = realloc(c_memory, sizeof(char) * SECT_SIZE * (*i_current_sect_size + SECT_EXTEND_SIZE));
    if(c_temp == NULL){
        printf("realloc failed upon %d + %d\n", *i_current_sect_size, SECT_EXTEND_SIZE);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        c_memory = c_temp;
        *i_current_sect_size += SECT_EXTEND_SIZE;
        printf("realloc success\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    //INITIALIZATION
    int i_current_sect_size;

    char *c_memory = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * SECT_SIZE * SECT_EXTEND_SIZE);
    if(c_memory == NULL){
        printf("c_memory malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    else
        i_current_sect_size = SECT_EXTEND_SIZE;

    memcpy(c_memory, "123456789012345", SECT_SIZE); //fill up 0th sector.
    //INITIALIZATION FINISHED


    for(int a = 0; a < MAX_SECT_TEST; a++){ //fill dummy data foreach sectors 
        if(a + 1 == i_current_sect_size)
            extend_memory(c_memory, &i_current_sect_size);

        memcpy(&c_memory[SECT_SIZE * a], &c_memory[SECT_SIZE * (a+1)], SECT_SIZE);
        printf("success %d\n", a);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In simple words, this program would repeatedly copy previous `SECT` value into next `SECT` as counter `a` increase. Upon reaching maximum allocated address, it would expand memory allocation using `realloc()` by `SECT_EXTEND_SIZE` and continue doing its job. This process done when `MAX_SECT_TEST` reached.

I ran the program with `SECT_SIZE` equal to `9`, `16`, `25`; All variations seems to fall into Segmentation Fault as it try to copy into SECT `15015`, `8446`, `5405` respectively.

9 x 15015 = 135,135

16 x 8446 = 135,136

25 x 5405 = 135,125

Why (135,125-135,136)th char become a limit?
I have a 8GB memory by the way. I'm pretty sure the actual limit should way bigger than that.

Comment: `memcpy(c_memory, "123456789012345", SECT_SIZE);` reads out of bounds (SECT_SIZE is 25)

Comment: Your `extend_memory` is essentially a wrapper for `realloc`. Why did you design its interface to be different from `realloc`? Why aren't you *returning* the new pointer value, like `realloc` does?

Comment: @M.M
thanks dude.

`realloc(*c_memory, sizeof(char) * SECT_SIZE * (*i_current_sect_size + SECT_EXTEND_SIZE));` need to changed as well besides two lines you corrected.

Comment: @AnT
To avoid realloc() failure, I guess, as suggested in other realloc() related questions.

Comment: @Shaziq: But you have already properly taken care of any possible `realloc` failures inside `extend_memory` (which is probably one of the reasons your `extend_memory` even exists). Now, once you've taken care of this issue, why wouldn't you keep the external interface unchanged? I mean, one big problem with the code is that you do not properly return the result to the calling code. You can fix it by going the `**` route (as suggested in the answers), or you can simply literally *return* it from the function. The latter looks more elegant to me.

Comment: regarding this line: `memcpy(c_memory, "123456789012345", SECT_SIZE);`  the value of `SECT_SIZE` is 25 but the literal is only 15 bytes plus NUL terminator byte.  So the code will be accessing beyond the upper bound of the literal.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when a `if` statement results in a call to `return` or `exit()`, then there is no need to write a explicit `else` clause.  If the `if` statement was not entered, then you have an 'implicit' else and nothing needs to be done

Comment: regarding the expression: `sizeof(char)`  per the C standard, that is always 1.   multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect on the value passed to `realloc()`.  All that expression does is clutter the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the parameters to `main()` are not being used.  This will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about `argc` and `argv`.  Suggest using the main() signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: Have you thought about this expression:  `SECT_SIZE * (*i_current_sect_size + SECT_EXTEND_SIZE) in the call to `realloc()`  that is 25 * (0 or 2500 or ...+100) so the first pass results in 2500 the second pass results in 71600, etc.  Probably not quite what you want.

Comment: in C, the returned value from the memory allocation functions (malloc, realloc, calloc) has type `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, leads to confusion, and makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain

Comment: the call to `malloc()`, in the function: `main()` results in 2500, not 100.  Suggest removing the multiplier by SECT_SIZE.

Comment: in main(), this line is not correct, because of the prior error in the call to `malloc()`.

Comment: this line: `memcpy(&c_memory[SECT_SIZE * a], &c_memory[SECT_SIZE * (a+1)], SECT_SIZE);`  is copying trash from `c_memory[SECT_SIZE * (a+1)` to the memory just set with the literal: `123456789012345`.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm aware of my unoptimized code and few bad practices. The main point is about the way I handling `realloc()` which already been solved.

Thanks for advises by the way. Appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
void extend_memory(char *c_memory, int *i_current_sect_size){
        ...
        c_memory = c_temp;
```

is effectively a noop and caller will not see the changed `c_memory`.

You will need to use an argument like `char **c_memory` and work with `*c_memory` within the function.

Comment: Either that, or make `extend_memory` *return* the new pointer, just like `realloc` does.

Comment: true; but because size is also adjusted and returned in a by-reference argument it might be more consistent to keep it as a parameter.  Alternatively, a `struct buffer { void *mem; size_t len };` can be declared and used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function to update a pointer value, you must pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
extend_memory(&c_memory, &i_current_sect_size);
```

and update your function as

```
void extend_memory(char **c_memory, int *i_current_sect_size){
...
  char *c_temp = realloc(*c_memory, sizeof(char) * SECT_SIZE * (*i_current_sect_size + SECT_EXTEND_SIZE));
...
  *c_memory = c_temp;
```